# How to click an empty space in Goutte?

Tags: php, laravel, goutte

The original document says; do that to click a link:

```
$crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Sign in')->link());
```

However, the area I would like to click is something like the code below. There is no text. In the browser, you can only see an icon.

```
<div id="Wrap" class="IconWrap">
    <span class="Icon">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Searched but could not find it. I would be happy to hear from you. If you have an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that ->link() does not accept any input other than < a > , therefore there has to be a real link to be recognised as a link.

Answer (score 1):

A Goutte is very light weight library. It just crawl through pages which is not loading dynamically. you can't do stuff like this which humans does. But you have to used tools like `selenium` or `puppeteer`.

you can do many things with these tools which human does. like  `CLick on button`
`Nagaviation through page` , `Submit forms` and many more.